# Scale text of SelectBox

Tags: java, libgdx, game-development

I am trying to use a SelectBox in a table. I know I can set the actor scale with `myTable.add(mySelectBox).size(100)` but this only changes the size of the box and does not scale the text inside it. How can I scale the text inside it?

```
public OptionsMenuScreen() {
    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    viewport = new FitViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2, cam);
    cam.setToOrtho(false, viewport.getScreenWidth(), viewport.getScreenHeight());
    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    cam.update();
    viewport.apply();
    stage = new Stage(viewport, game.batch);
}

@Override
public void show() {
final SelectBox<Integer> mySelectBox = new SelectBox<Integer>(mySkin);
        mySelectBox.setItems(0,5,10,20,30,60);
        mySelectBox.setSelected(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rotate / scale the nested component inside (Font, Texture, etc...), you may try the follow snippet.

```
mySelectBox.setTransform(true);
mySelectBox.setScale(2f);
```

[Group transform from libGDX's wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d#group-transform)